# Append only 1 row to CSV file each time

Tags: python

I use:

```
f = open("my_file.csv", "a")
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(['one', 'two'])
```

But instead of appending a new row after the last row, it appends 2 new rows: an empty one and then the required one "one| two". What is the reason for that?

Comment: cannot reproduce. Are you sure the empty line was not already there? To make your issue reproducible, please add a representative csv file, which when run through this code the issue is seen.

Comment: Yes. Even if I call this function two times, it adds a new empty line before the required line

Comment: Also are you sure this is all the code? You don't close the file after you write it, could you be appending more to it later in the code? I suggest using a `with` statement to ensure the file is closed properly, when you want it to be closed.

Comment: I do close the file... very weird

Comment: which python version and which os? Hopefully the with fixes it, it's good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to use `with open()` when writing to csv files. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). I can reproduce the problem you had on my machine, but the following code does not produce an empty line after each new line is appended.

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:      
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['one', 'two'])
```

Comment: Does this close the writer as well?

Comment: Yes, it automatically invokes the `close()` method as soon as you leave this code block.

Comment: @UFCInsider I don't think you need to close the writer. It's only an object whereas the file is a system resource. Were you to attempt to use the writer after the file was closed you'd hope that an exception would be thrown.